# Install OpenSUSE 11.1 on VM in Windows 7 Virtual PC

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-virtual-pc, opensuse

I setup a new VHD with Windows 7 Virtual PC RTM with 1GB Ram and booted up from the OpenSUSE 11.1 32-bit Installation disk. The install went fine without issue.

However, since the virtual machine was rebooted after setup it wont boot into OpenSUSE. It show the boot loader screen, but no matter which option I select (either "openSUSE 11.1" or "Failsafe") it just goes to a completely Black screen. It never actually goes into the OS or shows the Desktop.

Anyone have any insights into getting OpenSUSE working correctly with Windows 7 Virtual PC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very easy way of getting SUSE 11 up and going on a virtual machine is just download one of the pre made appliances that are offered. You can find several of them [here](http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html). Once you download the correct version, you would just need to make a new virtual machine and point that virtual machine to the directory containing the downloaded virtual's hard drive.

Good luck, and hope this helps some.

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me. I almost followed this tutorial: [http://flyjib.blogspot.com/2009/05/opensuse-111-on-virtual-pc-2007.html][1]
except i'm running a minimal installation (no KDE or Gnome)

I think the trick has to do with the boot options: noreplace-paravirt i8042.noloop clock=pit

good luck,
Peter